# Can we get 'Precise location' status ( on / off ) from iPhone setting in our app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, location, settings

We are looking for user current location but many times it's not accurate so we are thinking this is happening because of user Precise location is off so we want to check Precise location is on or off.

We are using **locationManager.accuracyAuthorization** to get Precise location status but it's not working with all users. Many time user's Precise location is on still it's showing off.

Here, I am sharing code what we have used.

```
var preciseLocation: String {
    var preciseLocation = ""
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        switch APP_DELEGATE.locationManager.accuracyAuthorization {
        case .fullAccuracy:
            preciseLocation = "on"
        case .reducedAccuracy:
            preciseLocation = "off"
        @unknown default:
            preciseLocation = ""
        }
    }
    return preciseLocation
}
```

If any one can help with this, it would be great.

Comment: That is the only way to access location accuracy. Btw "on" is probably a better default for pre-iOS 14 since there was no reduced location accuracy prior to iOS 14

Comment: This code sometimes gives incorrect results. There should be a better way to have 100% accuracy whether the user's precise location was ON or OFF.